# Installing TFS 2017 and cannot connect sql in other computer

Tags: tfs

In Server Configuration Wizard, in Database step, we have to provide the sql server instance name, but I cannot reach sql in other computer.

The screenshot below is from an installation guide:

[image]

The error message is the following:

[image]

I installed Management Studio and can connect to the sql server, but in the tfs installation i cannot. The firewall did not block the traffic because I have turned off all the firewalls

What roles is needed to connect SQL while installing TFS 2017?

Thanks any help in advance!

Comment: What error did you get? The screenshot showed you have passed the sql server instance test.

Comment: Thanks your reply, I have updated the question.

Comment: The problem is the same and I do not know how to grant permission to tfs installation user to reach Sql in another machine.

Comment: This dialog allows adding only local users to server role, but how can i add tfs server installation user on the other server? I do not understand why cannot provide a user (like sa user) in TFS Server Configuration Wizard installation to access SQL. I am not using domain controller in windows.

Comment: When you add the account in database, you can try `machinename\username` to see whether your two computers can be accessed.

Comment: I have tried that before, but the error message is the following:

Windows NT user or group 'XZY' not found. Check the name again. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15401)

Comment: You've mentioned you could connect to the sql server from SSRS, did you install SSRS on your TFS machine? For TFS, nly the single server configuration is supported in a workgroup deployment. Since you are using dual server configuration, you have to use  Active Directory environment. Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252507.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the account you plan to use to configure TFS is a member of the [SysAdmin server role in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017).

> Installing TFS involves a complex set of operations that require a
>   high degree of privilege - these include creating databases,
>   provisioning logins for service accounts, and more. Technically, all
>   that is required is membership in the ServerAdmin role; ALTER ANY
>   LOGIN, CREATE ANY DATABASE, and VIEW ANY DEFINITION server scoped
>   permissions; and CONTROL permission on the master database. Membership
>   in the SysAdmin server role will confer all of these memberships and
>   permissions, and is therefore the easiest way to ensure that TFS
>   configuration will succeed. If necessary, these memberships and
>   permissions can be revoked after TFS is installed.

More information you can refer to this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/install/dual-server?view=tfs-2018

Adding a screenshot:

[image]