# TFS not recognizing previous version database after updating SQL server from 2014 to 2017

Tags: sql-server, tfs

Updated SQL server from 2014 to 2017 by uninstalling SQL server 2014.

Later realized that there was no project collection in the TFS and unable to create the new project.

Upgraded TFS 2016 to TFS 2018, still it is unable to recognize the previous project.

Comment: Important note, there's no such thing as TFS 2016. That said, are you getting a **specific** error message? Where are you getting the error? You need to provide as much detail as you can if you want to get a useful answer.

Comment: Sorry, it is actually TFS 2015 update 1

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you may **not upgraded your database successfully.**

Instead of only uninstalling SQL server 2014 and directly install a new SQL 2017 version.

You need to move the databases to SQL 2014 or 2017 first. SQL will do the database upgrade, then you can run the TFS upgrade wizard.

You could also refer this [step-by-step tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/11/30/upgrade-to-team-foundation-server-tfs-2017/), even it's from TFS2015 to TFS2017(similar).

Comment: @Prasad Sorry, we are community supporter, could not directly connect with any customer. Besides, this is an open community site, to protect your privacy, suggest you to delete your previous comment. In case, reveal e-mail address to others. Instead, you could create an on-premises incident to obtain a professional support from our support link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/devops/

Comment: @Prasad For this case, have you verified and ensure that the account you used to configure TFS is a member of the **SysAdmin server role** in SQL Server 2017, also with local admin. You could take a look at this info from here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50462207/installing-tfs-2017-and-cannot-connect-sql-in-other-computer

Comment: @Prasad Thanks for your feedback. Recently, I also did a simple test to upgrade TFS 2015 to TFS2018 in my test environment. Try to reproduce the whole process and check if there is any important part missing. Everything works properly. A cack-handed way, restore your pre back up database to SQL 2014 and install TFS application tier 2015 and check if your collection is working fine. If so, then  do the upgrade process again.  If this way is still not working. Suggest you follow above support link to raise up a support ticket, our engineer will help you to look at this issue remotely.

Comment: database files are attached to SQL server 2017, how to downgrade ?
i tried to attach these files in another server with sql 2014, but it says version is higher and cannot be attached.
i tried exporting to .sql files, it got successes but while executing the script files  there was lot of errors. sql script file size was 14 GB

Comment: we will contact MS support